# Continue adding input file rows to table after an error using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I’m a newbie to SSIS, and have an issue with a package that has been puzzling me.

My company has SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008 (also, SQL Server 2008 R2).  On the Control Flow tab, I have two executables:  an Execute SQL Task (Truncate_crm_account_Table) that truncates the SQL Server crm_account table, and a Data Flow Task.

On the Data Flow tab, I have a Flat File Source that opens and reads a pipe-delimited file, and an OLE DB Destination that moves the rows in the input file to the crm_account table.

[Data Flow tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO0CN.png)

On the Event Handlers tab I have created an OnError Event Handler for the Truncate_crm_account_Table, and an OnError Event Handler for the Data Flow Task.  Both OnError Event Handlers are an Execute SQL Task object that writes the error encountered to a SQL Server error table.

This all works fine if there are no issues with the data.  When there is an error with the data (for example, on row 10,000), the package writes the records that have passed through its butter to the crm_account table (say, 9,000 or so records).  The package also writes the error to the error table, and then stops.  What the Project Manager would like the package to do is to continue processing the remainder of the input file after encountering  the error.

After reading through a number of forums and posts for SSIS issues that are somewhat related to mine, this is what I have done so far.  On the Control Flow tab, for the Data Flow Task, I’ve set MaximumErrorCount = 0 and noted that FailPackageOnFailure = False (also, FailParentOnFailure = False).  I’ve seen some posts that mention to set the System variable Propagate = False.  Both of these I’ve done, yet the package stops after encountering the error on row 10,000.

[System Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVaSh.png)

I don’t know how many records will be in the input file.  So, I believe that using a For Loop Container would not be a good object to add to the project.  As I’m very new to SSIS, I don’t know whether the ForEach Loop Container or some other object is the way to go.  How can this package be minimally modified so that it continues processing the remainder of the input file after encountering an error with the data?

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance for your time.

Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the data flow tab in the source node, find the error output section on the left side. Click it and change the applicable column in question to 'ignore failure' under the error column.

Comment: I made the change you suggested.  Of course, now the error is no longer logged to the error table.  While making the change to "Ignore failure", I noticed there was another option, "Redirect row".  I chose that option instead, and now the error row is written to a file.  It would have been better to have the error written to the error table, but this solution is a good alternative.